# How to extract all numeric values from a symbolic expression into a matrix?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, polynomials

I have done partial fraction decomposition to a symbolic polynomial in MATLAB, which gives me a symbolic expression like e.g. the following:

```
poly = -2i/(x - 1.0 - 1.7i) + 0.57i/(x - 1.0 + 1.1559i)
```

As you see, this symbolic expression contains both x-variables and constant complex numbers. How can I extract all the numeric values from this expression in MATLAB? The information whether the number is real or complex must not be lost.

So for the given expression `poly`, how would I get the following matrix `A`:

```
A = [-2i, -1-1.7i; .57i, -1+1.1559i]

A =

     0 - 2i        -1 - 1.7i
     0 + 0.57i     -1 + 1.1559i
```

Please also note that `A` should contain numbers, not symbolic expressions as `poly` does.

---

I read of `coeffs`-function, but it requires the input being a polynomial. 
With `children`-function I am able to divide the summation terms in the symbolic expression to vector of symbolic expressions as shown below:

```
p = - 0.57735026918962576450914878050196i/(x - 1.0 - 1.7320508075688772935274463415059i) + 0.57735026918962576450914878050196i/(x - 1.0 + 1.7320508075688772935274463415059i);
terms = children(p)

terms = 
[ -0.57735026918962576450914878050196i/(x - 1.0 - 1.7320508075688772935274463415059i), 0.57735026918962576450914878050196i/(x - 1.0 + 1.7320508075688772935274463415059i)]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me start with that I don't really know what you want to use this for. However, as long as your expressions follow this strict form (i.e. the sum of fractions of the form `A/(x+B)`), you can hack up a solution to your problem.

I'll be working with your sample input (renamed to `pol` in order not to shadow the function named `poly`):

```
x = sym('x');
pol = -2i/(x - 1.0 - 1.7i) + 0.57i/(x - 1.0 + 1.1559i);
```

First, cut this into two fractions with [`children`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/children.html):

```
fractions = children(pol);
frac1 = fractions(1);
```

Now, decompose a fraction using [`numden`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/numden.html):

```
[n,d] = numden(frac1);
A = n;
```

Now we have terms for a fraction of the form `A/(B*x+C)`, where `n == A` and `d == B*x + C`. You can extract the latter two parameters in multiple ways, I prefer calculus:

```
B = diff(d,x);
C = subs(d,x,0);
```

Now you know that your first fraction is `A/(B*x+C)`, or if you want you can divide `A` and `C` by `B` to get the "canonical" form of your fraction. Do the same for the second (and further, if any) child of `pol`.

Check:

```
>> simplify(frac1 == A/(B*x+C))

ans =

TRUE
```

Comment: @jjepsuomi no problem. Could you shed some light in a few sentences _why_ you need to do this? Odds are there are better ways to do what you're trying to do :)

Comment: sure I can :) I have used series expansion and partial fraction decomposition to integrate a hairy function. I received help earlier in this post https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2610119/53500. In the equations, I'm interested about the a_k, and b_k numbers, which are exactly that this code gives me. There are many steps to explain here, but what all this work is aiming for, is to test the asymptotic equivalence of cross-validation and Akaike information criterion using sinusoidal binary classifier with generalized linear models.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this sheds any light into my goal, and perhaps it could be done in an easier way. Nevertheless, there is a purpose for all this =) I need the numbers in order to define my generalized linear model, which I can then fit using maximum likelihood method.

Comment: @jjepsuomi thanks for the background! I can't say I understand after a brief glance, I'll try to take a closer look later:) But I acknowledge that you're doing this for a reason, that was my main concern.

Comment: No problem, I'm sorry for a bit brief summary but it's difficult to explain here very shortly. If I get everything working I will try to write everything down to a manuscript and maybe publish. This isn't any big result..just to test the theory in a non-trivial non-textbook-nice case.

Comment: @jjepsuomi oh, no, it's fine, you're not obliged to explain in detail, your question is self-contained as-is. I was just wondering if this might be an XY problem, which is why I asked :)

Comment: @AndrasDeak sorry to ask for more but, could you print the ´A, B, C´ variables? What do you get? I get (after running your code) A = 20, B = 10i and C = 17 - 10i. I was expecting the result (in frac1 case): A = -2i, B = 1, C = -1 - 1.7i.

Comment: @jjepsuomi as I hinted in my answer, the numerator and denominator of a fraction are undefined up to a factor. Both parametrizations are correct. Since you're looking for a canonocal form where the coefficient of `x` is 1, you need `a=A/B; b=C/B`.

Comment: @AndrasDeak oh yes, I apologize, I read the last part too hastily. I wasn't sure what canonical meant in this context. Excellent, now I got it. It works 100% very good. Thank you =)